# Measuring the "Adversity" of a Probability Distribution?

Tags: probability

In class today we saw the following example:

Imagine in a university there are 1000 students, and we know that the height of students has a normal distribution (with a specific mean and variance). **The normal distribution is so "powerful", that even if you take the heights of 5 random students, (on average, over many experiments) you still get pretty close to the actual average height of the population!**

Here is an R example that shows this:

```
set.seed(123)

my_data = data.frame(id = 1:100, height = rnorm(1000, 140, 5))

results = list()

for (i in 1:1000)

{

sample_i =  my_data[sample(nrow(my_data), 5), ]
mean_i = mean(sample_i$height)
results[[i]] = data.frame(i, mean_i)
}


final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

> mean(final$mean_i)
[1] 139.8691

   plot(hist(final$mean_i, main = "Distribution for the Average Height of 5 Randomly Selected Students (1000 Random Samples)"))
```

[image]

Now, suppose the 10 tallest people in the world join the university - repeating the same experiment produces a different histogram:

```
set.seed(123)

my_data_1 = data.frame(id = 1:100, height = rnorm(1000, 140, 5))
my_data_2 = data.frame(id = 100:110, height = rnorm(11, 230, 5))

my_data = rbind(my_data_1, my_data_2)

results = list()

for (i in 1:1000)

{

sample_i =  my_data[sample(nrow(my_data), 5), ]
mean_i = mean(sample_i$height)
results[[i]] = data.frame(i, mean_i)
}


final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

plot(hist(final$mean_i, main = "Distribution for the Average Height of 5 Randomly Selected Students (1000 Random Samples)"))

> mean(final$mean_i)
[1] 140.7412

> mean(my_data$height)
[1] 140.9521
```

[image]

Even in this case, it still only takes 5 random samples (on average, over many experiments) to get a pretty close answer - however, the first example provides less extreme results.

Having said this, I had the following question:

**Is it possible to measure the "adversity" of a probability distribution function?**

- For example - in the first case, it only took 5 random samples to get an estimate "close" to the actual mean.
- But in the second case, even though 5 random samples averaged over many experiments gave a close estimate to the actual mean - there were some instances in which a set of 5 random samples provided an estimate that was significantly different from the actual mean. **In a certain way, we could argue that the probability distribution in the second case provided us more "adversity" compared to the probability distribution in the first case.**
- Thus, is there some metric which can be used to measure the "adversity" of a probability distribution?

As an example - suppose the heights of students in University A are distributed with a normal distribution and the heights of students in University B are distributed with a gamma distribution : **If you were only able to take a set of 5 random samples from either of these universities, which of these sets has a higher probability of its mean being closer to the actual mean? Are such comparisons possible?**

Thanks!

Comment: You mean like variance? I guess the higher the variance the more "biased" sets you can make right?

Comment: Maybe this is better asked on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if I'm misinterpreting your question.

In this case, I'm not sure if the "adversity of a probability distribution" would quite be what we want since by adding the "10 tallest people in the world" to the university (which before adding, with 1000 students, had an average height of say $\mu_{\mathit{before}}$ with standard deviation $\sigma_{\mathit{before}}$), the population size and population parameters are then changed, e.g., assuming the heights of the 10 tallest people in the world are all greater than $\mu_{\mathit{before}}$, adding them to the population would cause the new average height, $\mu_{\mathit{after}}$, to be greater than $\mu_{\mathit{before}}$.

What might be more helpful is to look at the [efficiency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics)) of **estimators** of parameters of the population distribution as this gives us an idea of how many data points we need for our estimator to give us an estimate that is sufficiently close to the distribution parameter/parameters we're after.

For posterity, "the efficiency of an unbiased estimator, $T$, of a parameter [$\alpha$] is defined as:

$$e(T) = \frac{1/{\mathcal{I}}(\alpha)}{\mathrm{Var}(T)}$$

where $\mathcal{I}(\alpha)$ is the Fisher information of the sample." [1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics))  and $\mathrm{Var}(T)$ is the variance of the estimator.

I feel like this alternate view allows us to then separate our theoretical model and the analysis of what we actually observe as we can assume there is some fixed theoretical distribution for either case (with or without the 10 tallest people in the world) and then try to estimate the parameters of said theoretical distribution utilizing an "efficient" estimator.

**In an attempt to put things succinctly: In this case, "adversity" (or rather, an inversely related quantity) is a property that may make more sense to analyze as an attribute of an *estimator* of the parameters of a distribution instead of the distribution itself.**

With regards to the question of comparing the "closeness" of sample means to the true means of normal and gamma distributions, I think that requires a bit more specification as we can view these sample means as random variables themselves, meaning they have a distribution, and assuming finite moments, have a mean and a variance, too.

Let us assume that we have a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ as well as a gamma distribution with shape parameter $k$ and scale parameter $\theta$.

Assume that A is a random variable distributed according to the previously stated normal distribution and that B is a random variable distributed according to the previously stated gamma distribution.

We will refer to the mean of said normal distribution as $m_{N}$, and the variance of said normal distribution as $s_{N}^2$.

Similarly, we will refer to the mean of said gamma distribution as $m_{G}$ and the variance of said gamma distribution as $s_{G}^2$.

By definition, we have that $m_{N} = \mu$ and $s_{N}^2 = \sigma^2$.

By [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Mean_and_variance), we have $m_G = k\theta$ and $s_{G}^2 = k\theta^2$.

We will also refer to the sample means (which are random variables) calculated from 5 i.i.d draws from said normal and gamma distributions as $\hat{x}_N$ and $\hat{x}_G$, respectively.

One way to look at the "closeness" of the sample mean to the true mean would be to look at the squared difference between the true mean (a real number) and the sample mean (a random variable) **on average** which in our cases, would look something like:

$$\mathbb{E}[(m_{N} - \hat{x}_N)^2]$$ and $$\mathbb{E}[(m_{G} - \hat{x}_G)^2]$$

Note that these expressions are equivalent to the **variances** of
$(m_{N} - \hat{x}_N)$ and $(m_{G} - \hat{x}_G)$, respectively, and due to our assumption of i.i.d draws, can be simplified as follows:

$$\mathbb{E}[(m_{N} - \hat{x}_N)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(m_{N} - 5A/5)^2] = \mathbb{E}[m_{N}^2] - \mathbb{E}[2m_{N}A] + \mathbb{E}[A^2] = s_N^2 - m_N^2 = \sigma^2 - \mu^2$$

$$\mathbb{E}[(m_{G} - \hat{x}_G)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(m_{G} - 5B/5)^2] = \mathbb{E}[m_{G}^2] - \mathbb{E}[2m_{G}B] + \mathbb{E}[B^2] = s_G^2 - m_G^2 = k^2\theta^4 - k^2\theta^2$$

These quantities can then be compared to determine a form of "closeness" between the true mean and the sample mean that is based upon the distribution sampled from.